# How can I map a row_version column?

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, rowversion

I must mapping a `row_version` column in hibernate, I have a SQL Server database and my table has a row_version column on DB this column is declared as `timestamp` because for SQL Server a `rowversion` is a special timestamp.
How can I map this column in hibernate?

I tried to map this column as `Timestamp` as binary but it doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hibernate timestamp version controlled by database.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12864826/hibernate-timestamp-version-controlled-by-database)

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean? You got an error, unexpected behaviour, something *else*?

Comment: I have already tried this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12864826/hibernate-timestamp-version-controlled-by-database but I get tthe following error: Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @Temporal should only be set on a java.util.Date or java.util.Calendar property: it.vwgroup.il.agenda.model.entity.EventEntity.rowVersion
 at

Comment: share your entity's code

Comment: @Version
 @org.hibernate.annotations.Source(SourceType.DB)
 @org.hibernate.annotations.Generated(GenerationTime.ALWAYS)
 @Column(name = "ROW_VERSION")
 @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date rowVersion;

Comment: are you using `java.util.Date` or `java.sql.Date` ?

Comment: I have used java.sql.Date.

Comment: well, the exception that you are getting clearly says that `@Temporal should only be set on a java.util.Date or java.util.Calendar property` change `java.sql.Date` import to `java.util.Date` and it will work just fine

Comment: ok but with java.uti.date I  get the following error: Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Wrong column type in T_EVENT for column ROW_VERSION. Found: timestamp, expected: datetime

Comment: share schema of this table

Comment: CREATE TABLE [T_EVENT](
 [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [ROW_VERSION] [timestamp] NULL,
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

Comment: change type of `row_version` column to `datetime` instead of `timestamp`

Comment: I'm sorry but this column is already used in the code, my row_version column doesn't contains a date, in the documentation the rowversion should be correctly declared "timestamp"  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: I have used SQL Server 14.x